# SQL GROUP BY 1 2 3 and SQL Order of Execution

Tags: sql, group-by, operator-precedence

This may be a dumb question but I am really confused. So according to the SQL Query Order of Execution, the `GROUP BY` clause will be executed before the `SELECT` clause. However it allows to do something like:

```
SELECT field_1, SUM(field_2) FROM myTable GROUP BY 1
```

My confusion is that if `GROUP BY` clause happens before `SELECT`, in this scenario I provided, how does SQL know what `1` is? It works with `ORDER BY` clause and it makes sense to me because `ORDER BY` clause happens after `SELECT`.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

Comment: It's obvious to a human and a parser that the 1 refers to the field `field_1`. I took a quick look at your link and it has some fundamentally misleading information. It's saying you not rely on the SQL Query planner and rewrite your queries to do things a certain way. This is occasionally necessary but most of the time it isn't. SQL is _declarative_, not _procedural_

Comment: For example this corker "The where clause is used to limit the now-joined data". No. modern parsers will push a predicate down to _before_ a join if it will run faster. SQL does not do things in a certain order like that. It looks at your query and estimates the fastest way to do it then does it that way. It doesn't literally look at your query and do things in a certain order

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That ORDER BY is product specific.)

Comment: you cannot do a group by of numbers its only for order by i reckon!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is because it's **ordinal notation** and for the SELECT statement to pass syntax validation you have to have at least selected a column. So the 1 is stating the first column in the select statement since it knows you have a column selected.

EDIT:

I see people saying you can't use ordinal notation and they are right if you're using SQL Server. You can use it in MySQL though.

Answer (score 2):

`select a,b,c from emp group by 1,2,3`. First it will group by column a then b and c. It works based on the column after the select statement.

Answer (score -1):

Each `GROUP BY` expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. You cannot group by `1` if it is not a column in your table.

Comment: In MySQL you can group by column indexes